# Service Bus High CPU

Tags: 2016, workflow-manager, azure-service-bus

I am experiencing slowdown on my SP 2016 onprem dev farm with Workflow Manager installed. I have traced it to Microsoft.ServiceBus.MessageBroker.exe service:

[image]

Also, in Microsoft-ServiceBus/Debug event log I can see numerous warnings with Event ID 60006:

```
An exception was handled at workflowdefaultnamespace:Topic:sharepoint/default/bb146885-1dcc-4153-a780-8eb09f382513/aafa9933-d87a-4767-a6f2-a518e3bc1607/wftopic|MTW. Exception message Messaging entity 'workflowdefaultnamespace:Topic:sharepoint/default/bb146885-1dcc-4153-a780-8eb09f382513/aafa9933-d87a-4767-a6f2-a518e3bc1607/wftopic|MTW' is currently disabled for Receive operations., Stack Trace 
Server stack trace: 


Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Messaging.Broker.ComponentPartitionMessagingFactory.OnEndAcceptSessionReceiver(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Messaging.Broker.BrokerMessagingFactory.AcceptSessionReceiverAsyncResult.<GetAsyncSteps>b__67(AcceptSessionReceiverAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.EnumerateSteps(CurrentThreadType state)

Exception rethrown at [1]: 
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Messaging.Broker.BrokerMessagingFactory.EndAcceptSessionReceiver(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Messaging.Broker.NamespaceSessionManager.AcceptSessionAsyncResult.<GetAsyncSteps>b__9(AcceptSessionAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.EnumerateSteps(CurrentThreadType state).
```

Any help with this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, for me it was a relatively easy fix.

From event log record I recognized `sharepoint/default/bb146885-1dcc-4153-a780-8eb09f382513/aafa9933-d87a-4767-a6f2-a518e3bc1607` is actually a scope.

Then I looked at scopes in `WFResourceManagementDB` database and found out this particular scope was in `Suspended` status:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [ScopeId]
      ,[ParentScopeId]
      ,[DefaultWorkflowConfiguration]
      ,[WorkflowActivationThrottleThreshold]
      ,[WorkflowActivationThrottleTimeWindowInMinutes]
      ,[SecuritySettings]
      ,[Path]
      ,[Status]
      ,[HasTopic]
      ,[Description]
      ,[HasExceededTopicSizeQuota]
      ,[RevisionNumber]
      ,[Created]
      ,[LastModified]
      ,[LastRevised]
      ,[DisplayName]
      ,[RowVersion]
      ,[KeyRollingEnabled]
      ,[IsSnapshot]
      ,[IsSyncUpdate]
  FROM [WFResourceManagementDB].[dbo].[Scopes]
```

Eventually I ran the PS script to remove this scope since it was being used on a site collection which I don't use any more:

```
PS C:\script> Remove-WFScope -ScopeUri http://servername:12291/sharepoint/default/bb146885-1dcc-4153-a780-8eb09f382513/aafa9933-d87a-4767-a6f2-a518e3bc1607
```

That scope has changed it's status in the database to `Unregistered`.

And voila, the server is breathing again:
[image]

Hope this helps someone!